# Can't grep file correctly

Tags: shell, grep

I have a file with very simple syntax:

```
cat /tmp/test

ARCH=""prtconf -b | awk '/^name:/ {print $2}'
```

I tried to grep it:

```
cat /tmp/test | grep "prtconf -b | awk '/^name:/ {print $2"

ARCH=""prtconf -b | awk '/^name:/ {print $2}'
```

Let's make grep string a little longer, add } to the end:

```
cat /tmp/test | grep "prtconf -b | awk '/^name:/ {print $2"}
```

Nothing found

Why when I add } to the end of the line grep stop working?

OS is Solaris 10U11

Comment: read about the Useless use of Cat award. Less code means fewer opportunities for errors. Start using `grep 'srchTarg' file | otherstuff` as your standard form. Also note the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box. Select your code and click `{}` to get a better formatting for your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`$2` refers to command-line parameter so **here it will substitute blank character in a patter**. So you'l need to escape `$` by slash like `\$`

```
cat /tmp/test | grep "prtconf -b | awk '/^name:/ {print \$2}"
```

Without adding `}` in your patter it was working because it was matching actual pattern as `prtconf -b | awk '/^name:/ {print` for your input. But if you add `}` in your patter then it will try to match `prtconf -b | awk '/^name:/ {print  }` (which isn't there in your file so it won't show output.)